# What planners are available in Moveit?

Tags: ros, moveit, rrt, turtlebot, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I want to implement a new global path planner for turtlebots with RRTstar or TRRT which are available in [OMPL](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/planners.html). I have checked Moveit and didn't  find .cpp/.h files or infterfaces to RRTstar/ TRRT.  I also read tutorial of [Moveit](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Tutorials)  and didn't find any instruction on using Moveit for path planning, not to speak of RRTstar/TRRT.
Could  someone give me some advices on using Moveit for path planning with RRTstar?

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185524/what-planners-are-available-in-moveit?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-10**:
hi, @isucan, It is well-known that you are one of the greater founders of Moveit and OMPL. Would you like to give me some advices? Thank you!

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-15**:
Hi, @scopus, If you would like to know detailed information about OMPL, I recommend you to post to ompl-users@lists.sourceforge.net. I imagine that it is not better to directly ask a specific person on web site. I expect that your work will make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install `ros-hydro-ompl`? There is RRTstar.h in `opt/ros/hydro/include/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt`. Could you check it out? As OMPL is stand alone, you can add RRTstar.h to your code as follows.

```
#include <ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/RRTstar.h>
```

I'm sorry. you wanted to use RRTstar on MoveIt!, didn't you. I wrote how to implement RRTStar with OMPL. In case of MoveIt, some planners you want to apply to a PR2 appear on Rviz. I have never applied a planner to my turtlebot. I continue to edit my code with ompl to make a turtlebot move.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-21**:
Hi, Ken_in_JAPAN, I am also editing a code with ompl to make a turtlebot move. I just successfully compile the example code in Hydro as I told you. Next time I will try to build it into a global planner and move a turtlebot with it.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-21**:
Well, is my answer useful for you?

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-24**:
Hi, @Ken_in_JAPAN, thank you for your answer. But I encounterd another problem when I was doing this work. Please move to this new tips: http://answers.ros.org/question/187705/how-to-solve-this-problem-from-running-a-new-baseglobalplanner-in-move_base/, Hope you give me some valuable advices.